# Cannot load viewController using MFSidemenu

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am building an app using storyboard. I am using the MFSidemenu library for creating a sidemenu like facebook app. the side menu appears properly but when i tap a cell on the side menu, the menu doesnt go away and it doesnt load another view controller. Please note that i am using storyboard.

Thank you.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
AlbumsTableVIewController *AlbumsViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Albums"];

AlbumsViewController.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Demo Controller #%d-%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];


NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:AlbumsViewController];
self.sideMenu.navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
[self.sideMenu setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to implement delegate method to your `MainMenu` Controller, because if u place your code like above, it will change your sideMenu not ur `MainMenu`. i am working with storyboard here. this is my code on my `MainMenuController`

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.navigationController;

UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftSideMenuViewController"];
UITableViewController *SideMenu=(UITableViewController *)leftSideMenuViewController;
SideMenu.delegate=self; //here is the delegate
[MFSideMenu menuWithNavigationController:navigationController
                  leftSideMenuController:SideMenu
                 rightSideMenuController:nil];
```

so you need to hook up with your `viewController` from here, navigating thru delegate pattern.

Comment: can u please look up at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102600/how-to-change-centerview-on-click-of-tableview-row-of-leftsidecontroller-in-ipho having similar problem but am not using storyboard

Comment: can u please again try to open that link